# Simple pre-algebra re: GCF amd LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The second extra credit math problem for my god daughter (and yes she can get help). I thought I figured it out but, alas, I think not :(  Here goes:

Q: Positive integers a,b, and c, satisfy the following conditions:

GCF (a, b, c) = 1
GCF (a, b) = 3
GCF (a, c) = 4
GCF (b, c) = 5

What are the values of a, b. and c
And what is least value of LCM (a,b, c) * If I know how to calculate 1st part I;m sure I can figure 2nd part :) Oh, and I have to be able to relate this concept too

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\gcf}{\operatorname{GCF}}$Since $\gcf(a,b)=3$, we know that $a$ is a multiple of $3$, and since $\gcf(a,c)=4$, we know that $a$ is also a multiple of $4$; $3$ and $4$ are relatively prime, so $a$ must be a multiple of $3\cdot4=12$. Similar reasoning shows that $b$ is a multiple of $3\cdot5=15$, and $c$ is a multiple of $4\cdot5=20$. Thus, there are positive integers $k,m,n$ such that $a=12k$, $b=15m$, and $c=20n$. The smallest solution is $a=12,b=15,c=20$, and it gives you the smallest least common multiple of $3\cdot4\cdot5=60$.

Comment: That is what I got but had no real explanation other than that's what worked :) No way I could have told her how I got the answer so thank you very much! Totally appreciate the explanation and verification. Have a great evening

Comment: @Lorrie: You’re welcome.